# Reference name from Django database, NOT the id

Tags: python, django, sqlite, modelform

I am sending an email with object ID in a model, but I want to send the object names.

I have two models:

```
class Uniform(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length = 6)
    size = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {} - {} - ${}'.format(self.category, self.description, self.size, self.price)

class Transaction(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    uniform = models.ForeignKey(Uniform, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {} - {}'.format(self.employee_id, self.uniform, str(self.date))
```

And forms.py

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Transaction
        fields = '__all__'
```

My Views.py

```
def employeeCloset(request):
    form = TransactionForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TransactionForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            subject = 'Checked out item from Me'
            message = 'It is the responsibility of the team member to maintain all articles identified so that they are presentable and worn upon arriving according to standards required in the Employee Handbook. I understand I will be charged the deposit according to the cost identified below: \n {} \n These costs will be deducted from the team member’s paycheck and will be credited upon return of article(s). \n Any item that is not returned by the end of the pay period the cost of the item will be deducted from my paycheck. \n In order to receive full credit from items they must be returned by December 6, 2019.'.format(Uniform.__str__ == form.data['uniform'])
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_list = ['', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
            form.save(commit = True)

            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_list, fail_silently=False)

            return index(request)
        else:
            print('Error form invalid')

    return render(request, 'apparelapp/employeeCloset.html', {'form':form}
```

When sending email item views.py at **.format(form.data['uniform']** I get the uniform ID number **18** in the email, rather than getting the entire row. What I want it to say "Chef Coat, No Logo, 16.0, 4XL" not the unirform id:

[image: Uniform Description]

I have tried referencing the form uniform and then uniform value, no luck.

Thanks Django, Newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the id to look up the whole `Uniform` object:

```
uniform = Uniform.objects.get(id=int(form_data['uniform']))
```

And then you can refer to `uniform.description` to get the name.